# error in pushing the code in my private repository

Tags: git, upstream-branch

Can someone help me with below issue:
I cloned data from my professor Git url and trying to set my private account has upstream master and push the code in my private repository (https://github.com/accountid/reponame').

When I `git checkout -b branchname`, it is creating a new branch in my professors repo not in my account I want to create a master in my private repo.

But I am getting the below error:

```
 [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/accountid/reponame'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I push to my private repository?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read the error message.

You cannot push (unless using the force `-f`) to the remote repository if your local branch does not have the latest message.

Read the error and you will see that you need to perform pull before your push.

```
# pull changes from the server
git pull

# If you have conflicts resolve them and if not simply push to the server
# Assuming your remote is the  origin
git push origin <branch>
```

---

> When I `git checkout -b branchname`, it is creating a new branch in **my professors repo not in my account** I want to create a master in my private repo.

If the repository is not under your account and you are not contributor, you need to fork it first.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

First, check what origin points to:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

If origin still refers to your professor git url, then a push won't work, since you don't have the right to push to that repository (only clone/pull/fetch).

You should do:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://github.com/accountid/reponame
```

Second, check if you have a credential helper that could cache your HTTPS username/password credentials:

```
git config credential.helper
```